# различие версий PHP 5.2 и 5.5

Tags: php

На локальном сервере версия 5.5 следующее объявление функии работает:

```
function get_arr(&$arr, $fileName, $arrName='', $str_pos_arr=[]){
...
}
```

На хостинге версия 5.2, вылетает на этой строке с ошибкой:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ... on line xxx`

Как в версии 5.2 задать в качестве аргумента по умолчанию пустой массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как в версии 5.2 задать в качестве аргумента по умолчанию пустой массив?

```
$str_pos_arr = array();
```

На сайте PHP есть вся история изменений

http://php.net/manual/ru/migration53.changes.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.changes.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/migration55.changes.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/migration56.php

Comment: Спасибо большое, а ещё несколько вопросиков из той же темы тут можно?

Comment: 1. перестало работать file_get_contents: ´Warning: file_get_contents('do throw.as') [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in´ хотя файл на месте, может из-за пробела в имени? Вроде не нашёл чтобы там что-то менялось, как это поправить?

2. Warning: ´Invalid argument supplied for foreach()´ на строке

    foreach($lvltmp as $key => $value){

не понимаю отчего, всё вроде на месте

3. не было похоже функций curl_error() и curl_errno(): ´Warning: curl_error(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource´ У них были аналоги?

Comment: @Isaev, для решения последних двух проблем достаточно перевести текст ошибки. Для первой - прочитать про working dir и не указывать файлы относительно.

Comment: для первой проблема оказалась не в относительности путей, а что все строки стали с кавычками, т.е. он пытался найти файл с именем в котором вначале и в конце кавычки стояли